# the width just wont be one hundred percent

Tags: html, width

https://jsfiddle.net/jonathansh1115/oc75f0sr/

I read about many posts of the width would not be 100% and people always say

```
body {
margin=0;
padding=0;
}
```

will work but loooook at this!!

ps:i am using the bootstrap link there

Comment: What is the problem? The spaces around divs?

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are lots of issues with your code.

Firstly you are not using bootstrap properly. You have to add the `CSS` file also. Bootstrap will not work if you only include the `js` file. Once you include it then everything will work just fine.

The spacing around divs is because of the browser defaults. If you include Bootstrap they will just disappear. Also, you need to use bootstrap classes properly.

In my opinion, you should go through Bootstrap's documentation and then create your layout.  http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem you want that your 3 blocks have a 100% width. Here they have a 100% of 33.33% of your page because you have `col-sm-4`.
Try to replace by :

```
<div id="all">
        <div class="row col-sm-12" id="hqllo"><h1>hqllo</h1></div>
        <div class="row col-sm-12" id="nook"><h1>nooook</h1></div>
        <div class="row col-sm-12" id="pro"><h1>pro</h1></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work since there is `.row {
  width:calc(100%/3);
}`

Comment: Oh, okay didn't see that... But why use this css property with bootstrap and don't use the basic grid for simple things like that?

Answer (score 0):

remove this in `css`

```
.row {
  width:calc(100%/3);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ecjsc9rf/)